# Purple color text related with RowBox

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, string-manipulation, formatting, symbols

Type the first line of following code and press enter key.

```
RowBox[{"-", "(", "3", "+", "5", ")"}] // DisplayForm

-(3+5)
```

[image]

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

The output is `-(3+5)`. Now drag and copy the output and paste it to a new line.

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

[image]

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

Then you see a **purple colored closing parenthesis**.

This is a small thing, but I don't think it's normal. (or I did something wrong).

What do you think ?

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

After getting an answer :

```
RowBox[{"-", RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"3", "+", "5"}], ")"}]}] // DisplayForm

-(3+5)
```

If you copy the just above output `-(3+5)`, and paste it to a new line, this time there will be **no** purple parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though it looks like you can put all the symbols from a simple "linear" expression in one `RowBox`, this is not how Mathematica does it. It separates parts of expression in separate `RowBox`es to achieve a mathematically meaningful interpretation and proper code assistance.

```
-(3 + 5) // Unevaluated // ToBoxes
(* RowBox[{"-", RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"3", "+", "5"}], ")"}]}] *)
```

The purple color in your case – if you've never noticed it before – indicates an unbalanced parenthesis. It will also appear, for example, in `3 + 5)`.

Comment: A condensed answer, but the core is in the answer! Thank you for explaining clearly what I knew as just a feeling.

Comment: I've seen purple color text so many times. but never in case of so called `complete expression` like `(3+5)`. But I learned today that unconventional use of `RowBox` can lead to purple color text even in `complete expression`.