# Validate `Box` grammar, is it possible?

Tags: syntax, cells, boxes, parsing

Is it possible to validate grammar related to `Box` formed expression (`RowBox`, `FractionBox`, ...) ?

You can read following post first :

[Purple color text related with RowBox](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282972/purple-color-text-related-with-rowbox)

If you read the above post, you would know that

```
RowBox[{"-", "(", "3", "+", "5", ")"}] (*Expression 1*)

RowBox[{"-", RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"3", "+", "5"}], ")"}]}] (*Expression 2*)
```

*Expression 1* is rather an ill-formed expression, where as *Expression 2* is a good, impeccable expression.

Is there a built-in function or can we construct a function that can check the validity of `Box` formed expression ? And furthermore, can we construction a function that change ill-formed Box expression to good-formed Box expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may try using `` MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket[...]] ``.

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
 FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket[
  RowBox[{"-", "(", "3", "+", "5", ")"}]]]

(* RowBox[{"-", RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"3", "+", "5"}], ")"}]}] *)
```

As a "validation", you may try comparing the output to your input.

```
validateBoxes[boxes_] := 
 boxes === MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket[boxes]];

validateBoxes[RowBox[{"-", "(", "3", "+", "5", ")"}]]
(* False *)

validateBoxes[RowBox[{"-", RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"3", "+", "5"}], ")"}]}]]
(* True *)
```

Note that I haven't tested this on any other inputs, so I can't tell how reliable it is.

Comment: Rarely what I imagined really come true. Thank you!

Comment: And after 10 days, I am using it quite often. It is very practical.